# Strange RestKit / RKRequestQueue synchronous Issue

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, restkit, synchronous

I have an ARC-enabled project using `RestKit` and although most of my requests are done asynchronously, I am having an issue with performing a synchronous request:

In my `AppDelegate`:

```
else if (![IKUserController loggedInUserIsAuthenticated]) {
    IKLoginViewController *loginVC = [[IKLoginViewController alloc] init];
    loginVC.scenario = SCENARIO_EXISTING;
    [self.window.rootViewController presentModalViewController:loginVC animated:YES];
}
```

In the implementation for `loggedInUserIsAuthenticated`:

```
+ (BOOL)loggedInUserIsAuthenticated {
    IKUser *user = [IKUserController loggedInUser];

    if (!user) {
        return NO;  
    }
    else {
        NSString *username = user.userName;
        NSString *password = user.userPassword;

        if ([IKUserController loginWithUsername:username password:password]) {
            return YES;
        }
        else {
            return NO;
        }
    }

    return NO;
}
```

and the `loginWithUserName:password:`

```
+ (BOOL)loginWithUsername:(NSString *)username password:(NSString *)password {

    //return YES;

    NSDictionary *params = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithObjectsAndKeys:username, @"username", password, @"password", nil];

    RKResponse *response = [[[RKClient sharedClient] post:@"/user/authenticate" params:params delegate:nil] sendSynchronously];

    if (response.isOK) {
        return YES;
    }
    else {
        return NO;
    }

    return NO;
}
```

and the error:

```
*** Assertion failure in -[RKRequestQueue removeRequest:decrementCounter:], /Users/admin/Documents/dev/RestKit/Code/Network/RKRequestQueue.m:350
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The RKClient method *post* already adds the request to the default request queue, so I think the problem is that you send the request twice - once async and once sync. Instead of using RKClient *post* method, configure the request manually. There is a method *setupRequest* on RKClient, this will make it easier for you and you will only need to define the url, method and params, like this:

```
RKRequest* req = [RKRequest requestWithURL:reqURL delegate:self];
[req setMethod:RKRequestMethodPOST];
[req setParams:params];

[client setupRequest:req];

[req sendSynchronously];
```

Comment: I ended up just making these async like the rest of my requests, but this is correct